# Pandas merge on first column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two pandas dataframes that have duplicate rows (here the rows consisting of 2's corresponding to 'a' and 'b') among the entries I am trying to merge. As a result, pandas is taking a cartesian product of the duplicate rows as shown below:

```
In [8]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 2], 'b' : [2, 2, 2], 'c' : [3, 6, 6]}) 

In [9]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [2, 2], 'b' : [2, 2], 'd' : [2, 5]})          

In [10]: df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['a', 'b'])                             
Out[10]: 
   a  b  c    d
0  1  2  3  NaN
1  2  2  6  2.0
2  2  2  6  5.0
3  2  2  6  2.0
4  2  2  6  5.0
```

The result I want is to only have the merge done once between each duplicate row, in the order that they appear (in this case numerically by the index). So the output that I would like to have is:

```
In [12]: df_output = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 2], 'b' : [2, 2, 2], 'c' : [3, 6
    ...: , 6], 'd' : [np.nan, 2, 5]})                                           

In [13]: df_output                                                              
Out[13]: 
   a  b  c    d
0  1  2  3  NaN
1  2  2  6  2.0
2  2  2  6  5.0
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Wont drop_duplicates do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You need helper column by counter created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 2], 'b' : [2, 2, 2], 'c' : [3, 6, 6]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [2, 2], 'b' : [2, 2], 'd' : [2, 5]})    

df1['g'] = df1.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()

df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['a', 'b', 'g'])  
print (df)
   a  b  c  g    d
0  1  2  3  0  NaN
1  2  2  6  0  2.0
2  2  2  6  1  5.0
```

Last remove `g` column:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['a', 'b', 'g']).drop('g', axis=1)  
print (df)
   a  b  c    d
0  1  2  3  NaN
1  2  2  6  2.0
2  2  2  6  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `drop_duplicates` solve your problem?

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['a', 'b'])
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will suffice

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer').drop_duplicates()
```